# Are there good ebook management tools available for free?

Tags: windows, free, linux, mac-os, ebook-management

I have a collection of e-books and I am looking for a way to manage it from my operating system. What are the programs to manage e-books available for free? I use both Linux and Windows OS, can you suggest some good software?

Comment: [Software Recommendations](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/search?q=ebook+is%3Aquestion) has some good pointers too…

Comment: Calibre used to be excellent. Now it refuses to recognises readers, which makes it useless. Tried uninstalling and re- installing several times but I have now given up. I am looking for one to take its place now.

Comment: @BrianHarper what sort of reader? It works fine still with my Kobo.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Calibre is a free and open source e-book library management application available. You can download from [here](http://calibre-ebook.com/download) which is available for all operating systems.

Adobe Digital Editions is also one of the e-book manager by Adobe. You can access it from [here](http://www.adobe.com/products/digital-editions.html).

Alfa Ebooks Manager features a lot of templates and options for library vizualization. Besides, it allows to update book data from multiple web sources (like Amazon, Google Books, Barnes & Nobel, etc). It's also good at file management and metadata extraction. You can download it from [here](http://www.alfaebooks.com/products/alfaebookmanager/download).

Delicious Library's a bit different. Actually it's a software not just for books but for managing all stuff at your home. It's greates feature - entering books via webcam shot (it recognizes ISBN code). This feature makes Delicious Library the best software for collecting paper books. You can see the details from [here](http://www.delicious-monster.com/get/).

And if you are a mac user Delicious Library is the best e-book manager but unfortunately it's not free. Second priority I will give to Alfa eBooks Manager.

Hope it will help!

Comment: You should mention the downside to using Calibre (or maybe some of the other if it also applies to them) - It copies the ebooks to it's own directory based "database" - so If you want to keep the original directory structure of your library, you'd have to keep two copies of your library... and you have to maintain both to keep them synchronized.

Answer (score 18):

### Calibre

It is the leading ebook management tool.  However, you should be aware when you do add a title into Calibre it will embed a bookmark file in the `META-INF` folder and will modify your `.opf` file.  Other than that it is avaiable for all environments:

- [Calibre for Windows](http://calibre-ebook.com/download_windows); [64-bit](http://calibre-ebook.com/download_windows64)
- [Calibre for Mac](http://calibre-ebook.com/download_osx)
- [Linux](http://calibre-ebook.com/download_linux); How to install on Ubunutu:

  `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:n-muench/calibre
   sudo apt-get update 
   sudo apt-get install calibre`
- [Portability on a thumb drive](http://calibre-ebook.com/download_portable)

### Adobe Digital Editions

Free and from Adobe.  Be advised there has been some issues lately in viewing DRM `.epub` 3.0 ebooks and the fonts not rendering correctly.  This is a bug that was introduced a few months ago on the update but no word yet on when the issue will be addressed.  Download page for [Adobe Digital Editions](http://www.adobe.com/products/digital-editions/download.html).  You can install ADE on Ubuntu but you will need Wine.  Good article read: ["Howto install Adobe Digital Editions on Ubuntu 12.04 and use it with an e-book reader"](http://robert.penz.name/440/howto-install-adobe-digital-editions-on-ubuntu-12-04-and-use-it-with-an-e-book-reader/)

### BookONO

A management tool I haven't tested or used but they are trying to compete with Calibre so it could be a worthy alternative: [BookONO E-book Manager](http://etopian.com/software/bookono/)

### Adobe PDF Reader

You mention ebooks but not what type.  So just throwing [Adobe PDF Reader](http://get.adobe.com/reader/) for web `.pdf`s.  Good write up over at AskUbuntu on installing adobe PDF reader on Ubuntu: "[How do I install Adobe Acrobat Reader?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/89127/how-do-i-install-adobe-acrobat-reader)"

**A few others I've heard but haven't used:**

- [Delicious Library 3](http://delicious-monster.com/)
- [Alfa Ebooks Manager](http://www.alfaebooks.com/)
- [Moon+ Reader](http://www.moondownload.com/)
- [All my books](http://www.bolidesoft.com/allmybooks.html)
- [Data Crow](http://www.datacrow.net/)
- [Lucidor](http://lucidor.org/lucidor/)

---

After the added tag [mac-os](/questions/tagged/mac-os):

- [iBooks](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/ibooks/id364709193?mt=8)
- [KooBits](http://www.koobits.com/)
- [Scida](http://getscida.com/)

Answer (score 4):

Jeboorker is also a look worth. I use it to manage my local epub and pdf ebooks. It's open source, and available for Linux and Windows. You can downlaod it [here](https://code.google.com/p/jeboorker/).

Answer (score 2):

Google Play Books is a good cloud option.  They have [iphone](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/google-play-books/id400989007?mt=8), android, and [web](https://play.google.com/store/books?utm_source=HA_Desktop_US&utm_medium=SEM&utm_campaign=gplaunch&pcampaignid=MKTAD0715PY).  If you are looking for conversion functionality and more than just a library / reading, calibre as mentioned is useful.

Answer (score 0):

If you have Firefox browser, you can try [EPUB Reader](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/user/epubreader/?src=api) add-on.

Simple clean interface, and good performance because it's using Firefox.